# JavaScript Alert/Confirm Error

Tags: javascript, html, alert

Currently when new users register at my website, they have to fill out some forms. If their password is too short, doesn't match, they don't fill out all of the fields, or any other error, I want to alert them of it. Currently it does not alert them, so I switched to confirm. That didn't work either so I considered using `showModalDiaglog`. That also didn't work, I am out of Ideas. I currently have this:

HTML

```
<form>
    First Name:<br/> <input id="firstname"/><br/>
    Last Name: <br/> <input id="lastname"/><br/>
    Age:       <br/> <input id="age"/><br/>
    Your Email:<br/> <input id="email"/><br/>
    Username:  <br/> <input id="username"/><br/>
    Password:  <br/> <input id="password"/><br/>
    Confirm Password:<br/> <input type="password" id="passwordconfirm"/><br/>
    <br/>
    <button size=20 onClick='getRegistrationFields()'>Submit</button>
  </form>​
```

JavaScript

```
function getRegistrationFields() {
var first = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
var last = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElemetnById("password").value;
var confirm = document.getElementById("passwordconfirm").value;
var empty = "";

if ((first === empty) || (last === empty) || (email === empty) || (age === empty)
    || (username === empty) || (password === empty) || (confirm === empty)) {
    var message = "Not all of the fields are filled out";
    prompt(message);
    //showModalWindow("fields");
    return false;
   }

else {
   age = parseInt(age);

   if (password.length < 10) {
        var message2 = "Password must be at least 10 characters long";
        prompt(message2);
        //showModalWindow("passwordlength");
        return false;
       } 

   else if (password != confirm) {
        var message3 = "Passwords Do not match";
        prompt(message3);
        //showModalWindow("passwordmatch");
        return false;
       }

   else if (age < 18) {
        var message4 = "You must be older to register for this software.";
        prompt(message4);
        //showModalWindow("young");
        return false;
       }

   else {
        var message5 = "All of the fields are correct. We will be processing your request";
        prompt(message5);
        //showModalWindow("success");
        return true;
       }
  }
}

function showModalWindow(fileName) {
   window.showModalDialog("alerts/" + url + ".html", "", "resizable: no; height: 150;   width: 350;");
}
```

Comment: @mgraph What exatley do you mean?

Comment: just a note, `password` in your html is a normal textbox.... Might want to change that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

html:

```
<button size="20" id="btn_submit">Submit</button>
```

js:

```
var btn_submit = document.getElementById("btn_submit");
btn_submit.onclick = getRegistrationFields;
```

Comment: You are assigning the return value of a function call to `onclick`. That makes no sense unless the called function returns a function which is not the case here. Remove the `()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo:

```
var password = document.getElemetnById("password").value;
```

You wrote `getElemetnById` instead of `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

Make it easy on yourself.

```
  <input type="password" class="password" />
    <input type="text"  class="age" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        !(function () {
            var txBxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=textbox]'),
                i = txBxs.length;
            while (i--) {
                tkBxs[i].onchange = textBoxCheck;
            };
        }());
        //
        function textBoxCheck() {
            //
            switch (this.class) {
                //
                case 'password':
                    if (this.value.length < 10)
                    { alert('Password to short'); };
                    break;
                    //

                case 'age':
                    if (+this.value < 18)
                    { alert('To young kiddo!'); };
                    break;
            };
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Haha +1 for "Too young kiddo!"

Comment: Horrible indentation style for your `if` bodies though.